# Different column length PrettyTable

Tags: python

Is it possible to get different lengths in column's in prettytable? When I try to use a list in PrettyTable I get the error: column length's do not match. Because one list has more items in it then the other list.

Example:

```
ListA = ("111", "222")
ListB = ("333")
```

PrettyTable:

```
t = Prettytable([])
t.add_column('Test1', ListA)
t.add_column('Test2', ListB)
print(t)
```

Comment: Why don't you make the columns the same length?

Comment: Because the lists are not the same length, one has 10 items in it and the other 5.

Comment: Use the approach from the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

workaround this problem using `zip_longest` and a fill value, wrapped in `zip` again to add title:

```
import itertools

titles = ('Test1','Test2')
ListA = ("111", "222")
ListB = ("333",)

t = Prettytable([])

for title,lst in zip(titles,itertools.zip_longest(ListA,ListB,fillvalue="")):
    t.add_column(title,lst)
```

that will generate a sequence of the length longest list, padded with empty strings for shorter lists (and as a bonus you use a loop and not multiple `add_column` calls)

Comment: I get the following error when I try that: Exception: Column length 0 does not match number of rows 1!